# Asyncio loop.run_until_complete() on recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.5, future, python-asyncio

I am trying to teach myself asyncio so as an exercise I built a [web scraper](https://github.com/brucepucci/asyncio_scraper/blob/master/get_gids_async.py). The main working peice is the following recursive function...

```
async def get_gids(base_url='http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/'):
    soup = await get_soup(base_url)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        dest = link.get('href')

        fut = asyncio.Future()

        def set_result(out):
            try:
                fut.set_result(out.result())
            except:
                pass

        if dest.startswith('year_') and dest[YEAR] in VALID_YEARS:
            in_fut = asyncio.ensure_future(get_gids(base_url + dest))
            in_fut.add_done_callback(set_result)
        elif dest.startswith('month_') and dest[MONTH] in VALID_MONTHS:
            in_fut = asyncio.ensure_future(get_gids(base_url + dest))
            in_fut.add_done_callback(set_result)
        elif dest.startswith('day_'):
            in_fut = asyncio.ensure_future(get_gids(base_url + dest))
            in_fut.add_done_callback(set_result)
        elif dest.startswith('gid_'):
            if await is_regular_season(base_url + dest):
                print('gid: {}'.format(dest))
                gids.append(dest)
        else:
            pass
```

In a `run_forever` loop this works great. However, It is desired that it runs and finishes without me having to kill it, something like `run_unitl_complete(get_gids())` but this seems not to work as I only get the first page back. I tried this...

```
f = asyncio.wait(get_gids())  
loop.run_until_complete(f)
```

Again with no success as a TypeError gets raised... `TypeError: expect a list of futures, not coroutine`

What can I do to run the loop until the original function call gets popped off the call stack?

Comment: how were you scheduling `get_gids` using `run_forever`?

Comment: ```loop = asyncio.get_event_loop(); asyncio.ensure_future(get_gids(base_url)); 
loop.run_forever()```

Comment: I wanted to up-vote your question because it is really curious and useful in understanding the theory. But your code snippet is way complex and specific. I spent pretty much time to simplify it an capture the essence. Please make your code simpler and more common. It could help people!

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a warning from `asyncio` since your current code creates a task but does not `await` it or return it for something else to do it.

```
import asyncio

def callback(f):
    print("Callback: {}".format(f.result()))


async def non_awaiting_coro():
    print("Executing non awaiting coroutine")
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.sleep(0.25))
    fut.add_done_callback(callback)
    print("Done executing coroutine")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(non_awaiting_coro())
```

Returns the following:

```
Executing non awaiting coroutine
Done executing coroutine
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<sleep() running at ...>
```

Notice the callback was not fired. If you do await `fut` the coroutine should complete:

```
async def awaiting_coro():
    print("Executing coroutine")
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.sleep(0.25))
    fut.add_done_callback(callback)
    await fut
    print("Done executing coroutine")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(awaiting_coro())
```

which returns:

```
Executing coroutine
Callback: None
Done executing coroutine
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tried a tricky thing - asynchronous recursion. As you may noticed there is a warning:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_gids' was never awaited

It means that a coroutines which you recursively created didn't started not in a loop neither with `await`. You can find a description of the behavior in the doc:

> Calling a coroutine does not start its code running – the coroutine object returned by the call doesn’t do anything until you schedule its execution. There are two basic ways to start it running: call await coroutine or yield from coroutine from another coroutine (assuming the other coroutine is already running!), or schedule its execution using the ensure_future() function or the AbstractEventLoop.create_task() method.

While you scheduled only the first created coroutine with `run_until_complete`. Other coroutines could be scheduled if a loop is running.

It is possible to fix the situation with **`await`ing inside of the coroutine**, but it is a blocking approach so it is a bit senseless:

```
async def recursive(arg=0):
if arg < 10:
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(recursive(arg+1))
    fut.add_done_callback(lambda out: print(out))
    await fut

    # Simulation of extra ections                                 
    count = 3                                    
    while count:                                 
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())     
        count -= 1                               
return arg


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(recursive())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also you can use a **global loop to run all the coroutines**:

```
LOOP = asyncio.get_event_loop()                      
TASKS = []                                           

async def recursive(arg=0):                                                                 
    if arg < 10:                                     
        fut = asyncio.ensure_future(recursive(arg+1))
        TASKS.append(fut)                            
        fut.add_done_callback(lambda out: print(out))

        # Simulation of extra actions.               
        count = 3                           
        while count:                                 
            count -= 1                               
            await asyncio.sleep(random.random())     
    return arg                                       


# Stop the loop when everything is done                                
async def shutdown():                                
    while not all(i.done() for i in TASKS):          
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)                      
    LOOP.stop()                                      


def main():                                          
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(recursive())         
    TASKS.append(fut)                                
    asyncio.ensure_future(shutdown())                
    LOOP.run_forever()                               


if __name__ == "__main__":                           
    main()
```

This approach is pretty far from a good architecture with all the global variables but it captures the essence. Also it matches your requirement

> It is desired that it runs and finishes without me having to kill it

To make it happen you need to have a coroutine which closes a loop when everything is done.